# what is wrong with the function overwritten in lua?

Tags: function, lua, return

```
function f()
  return 1
end

function f(N)
  if N == 42 then
    return f()
  else
    return 2
  end
end
```

f is overwritten, but f(42) returns 2 instead of 1. Why? Is this possible?

Comment: Why would it ever return 1? You said yourself that the original `f` was overwritten. Or is the question why did this not loop until it broke?

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't think it would ever break thanks to TCO anyway.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't overload a function in Lua. You can just "redefine" it. So :

```
function f(N)
  if N == 42 then
    return f()
  else
    return 2
  end
end
```

N = 42, so you call `F(N)` with `N == nil`, then it returns 2.

Answer (score 3):

`N` is nil in the second call to `f`.

Answer (score 3):

`N` is `nil` in the 2nd case:

`f(42)` calls `f()` recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
f = function ()
  return 1
end

f = function (N)
  if N == 42 then
    return f()
  else
    return 2
  end
end

print(f(42))
```

The first assignment creates a function value and assigns it to `f`.

The second assignment creates a different function value and assigns it to `f`. (The first function value is now dead.)

The third statement calls the value of `f` as a function with an argument of `42`.

As others have explained, in the second function, `return f()`, calls the value of `f` as a function with no arguments. The value of `f` at that point is the second function. So, in the second call, `N` is `nil`.